# Programatically adding Custom ImageView in MainActivity

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I want to dynamically add my custom ImageView to the MainActivity which already contains a EditText such that the whole space under EditText should be covered by ImageView. Then I would draw something on ImageView upon TouchEvent and accordingly output some text to EditText. But nothing is working out with my approach. Please help.
*activity_main.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/RL"
 >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
BondImage BI;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    BI = new BondImage(this);           
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

BondImage.java

```
public class BondImage extends ImageView{

Canvas c;
Paint p;
Bitmap bm;
float x, y;
public BondImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Config.ARGB_8888);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RL);
    rl.addView(this, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    c = new Canvas(bm);
    p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    x = y = 0;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
    c.drawCircle(x, y, 25, p);   //example
    this.setImageBitmap(bm);
    x ++; y ++;
            /*  and some other stuff  */
    return true;        
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by: "But nothing is working out with my approach"? do you have an error message?

Comment: its runtime error.Message : "app has stopped working"

Comment: show your full logcat output..

Comment: here it is : http://collabedit.com/t9spe

Comment: @Bond : move `bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Config.ARGB_8888);` after `rl.addView....` line and still getting same error then pass some static height/width   instead of `MATCH_PARENT`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no affect, tried both.still same runtime error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, finally I modified my approach ( actually that was what I thought initially, but still I am not satisfied with that )
I created a static ImageView below the EditText and Used it for handling MotionEvents and drawing directly. For MotionEvent I had to normalize coordinates, as simply using getX and getY would give coordinates relative to whole view But I needed them relative to ImageView .Downside of this approach is that its somewhat slow, thats why I was excusing myself from using it. But right now I have no other approach in my mind to handle both EditText and custom ImageView in the same activity.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

BI = new BondImage(this); has not been added to layout view that y its not showing up

try

```
setContentView(BI);
```

Comment: but I am adding it in the BondImage class itself! I have also tried other way round. means adding it to the layout in the MainActivity class itself. None of the approach works.

Comment: Yeah it would work for ImageView but then how EditText would be displayed ?

Comment: huh u didnt realize from this experiment that when you set on view there is no place for other to fit it that means you are filling parent whichever call first so no place other Got MR.BOND

Comment: But I have seen some apps working that way. There has to be some way!